# How can I improve a simple join on a very small table? (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a large table with a foreign key to a smaller table:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
  make_model_id INTEGER INDEXED REFERENCES models (make_model_id),
  color TEXT INDEXED,
  year INTEGER INDEXED,
  details TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE models (
  make_model_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  make TEXT,
  model TEXT
);
```

cars is hundreds of millions of rows, while models has about 30 rows total.  Most queries look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars JOIN make_model USING (make_model_id)
WHERE
  color = 'green' AND
  year = 2015 AND
  make = 'Honda';
```

Looking at EXPLAIN, the query planner does a nested loop to join the two tables rather than collecting the rows from `models` and using the index on `cars`.  If I manually run `SELECT make_model_id FROM models WHERE make = 'Honda';`, that result is instant, then if I use the result in the original query with an IN clause, it shortens the run time by more than half.  Is there a way to do this two-step process in a single query?

I've tried moving the query to an in-line clause (`make_model_id IN (SELECT make_model_id FROM models...`) and as a CTE, but both yield near-identical performance to the original query.

Comment: could you please add output of explain analyze for your query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Do you have one index on `(color, year)` or two separate indexes on `color` and `year`? Does running `analyze cars` change anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best index

```
CREATE INDEX ON cars (color, year);
```

Make sure that you have correct statistics, particularly on the small table:

```
ANALYZE make_model;
ANALYZE cars;
```